# How to hide video in a surfaceview and keep audio playing

Tags: android

I am using a mediaplayer on surfaceview and playing a video file. I dont want the video to be displayed but audio must be audible. Seen some of the questions and tried them, no help.  Somebody please help.

Comment: What do you want displayed instead of the video?

Comment: Nothing..i just want the audio from the video. or may be just the thumbnail of video will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout and put an ImageView (with match_parent for width and height) above the SurfaceView in your layout.  Set the source for the ImageView to a thumbnail and let the video play behind it (but not visible to the user).